# How can I count the number of edges after applying Canny edge detection?

Tags: python, count, edge-detection, canny-operator

I have an image, and I apply the `feature.canny` algorithm to it in order to get the edges of the image.

[image: original image(left) vs edge detection(right)]

Now I want to **count** the edges in the image in order to obtain a single number.

Can anyone help?

This is the code to display the images:

```
def canny_detection(image):

    # Convert to grayscale and convert the image to float
    RGB = img_as_float(color.rgb2gray(image))

    # Apply Canny edge detection algorithm
    edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB, 2)

    # Plot results
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(RGB, cmap=cm.gist_gray)
    plt.title('Original image')
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(edge_canny, cmap=cm.gist_gray)
    plt.title('Canny edge map')`
```

I also have some code that applies Canny and then extracts the array from the image, if this is helpful:

`def canny_detection(image):`

```
# Convert to grayscale and convert the image to float
RGB = img_as_float(color.rgb2gray(image))

# Apply Canny edge detection algorithm
edge_canny = feature.canny(RGB,3)
#print(edge_canny)
edge_canny = edge_canny.astype(int)
#print(edge_canny)

#Get output array
canny_arr = np.array(edge_canny)

# Flatten output array
canny_flat = canny_arr.flatten()
#print(np.count_nonzero(canny_flat))   #to see if the matrix is all zeros

return canny_flat
```

So from the image with edge detection, I want to count the number of edges. I'm not really sure how to do this, so any help would be great!

Comment: interested to see if a solution was found for this?

Comment: @user14578710 This was a while ago, but this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889712/gradient-of-edges-python was useful in figuring out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the number of connected components.

But any measure of the number of edges will be very poor, especially in textured images, as edge detection is an ill-posed problem and depending on the noise level and detector settings you can obtain very different results for the same scene.

Personally, I would never use this parameter.