# Gradient of edges Python

Tags: python, image-processing, canny-operator

I have a dataset with two classes of images: Cityscape and Landscape. What I want to do is calculate the gradient(orientation) of the edges of each image and show that images of cityscapes have more vertical/horizontal edges than landscape images.

What I've done is calculated vertical, horizontal, 45 degree and 135 degree edges. I've applied a Canny filter to the images, calculated the x,y gradients and also applied a threshold to the images show it shows edges above that threshold. The result of this thresholding is seen here: [image: Cityscape edges]

This is my code for this image manipulation as well as calculating the gradients:

```
def gradient(image):    

    # Step 1
    img = image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Step 2
    bi = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 15, 75, 75)

    # Step 3
    dst = cv2.Canny(bi, 100, 200)
    #print(np.count_nonzero(dst))  #--> make sure it's not all zeroes

    # Step 4
    #--- create a black image to see where those edges occur ---
    mask = np.zeros_like(gray)

    #--- applying a threshold and turning those pixels above the threshold to white ---           
    mask[dst > 0.1 * dst.max()] = 255

    # Step 5
    img[dst > 0.1 * dst.max()] = [255, 0, 0]   #--- [255, 0, 0] --> Red ---

    Gx = cv2.Sobel(mask,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    Gy = cv2.Sobel(mask,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    #orientation of the edges
    theta = np.arctan2(Gy, Gx)

    #magnitude
    M = np.sqrt(Gx*Gx + Gy*Gy)

    #Vertical edges: 
    v = abs(Gy)

    #Horizontal edges: 
    h = abs(Gx)

    #45 Degree edges: 
    deg45 = M*abs(np.cos(theta - np.pi/4))

    #135 Degree edges: 
    deg135 = M*abs(np.cos(theta - 3*np.pi/4))

    print('Vertical:')
    #print(v)
    print(np.count_nonzero(v))
    print('Horizontal:')
    #print(h)
    print(np.count_nonzero(h))
```

What I want is to calculate the `v,h,deg45,deg135` for the edges shown as red in the image above (Step 5). If that is not possible, then do that for the image with the white edges (Step 4). Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** So as to avoid confusion, what I want to do is to get the amount of vertical, horizontal etc edges in a given image, so that I can compare those numbers for cityscapes vs landscape images.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " calculate the v,h,deg45,deg135 for the edges"?

Comment: I have formulas for the vertical, horizontal, 45 degree and 135 degree angle gradient. What I want to do is for each red edge in the image, to find the gradient of the edge and then count the number of vertical, horizontal etc. for each image

Comment: What do you mean by vertical, horizontal, etc gradient?  The gradient is  a vector and shouldn't change with direction.  Do you want the projection of the gradient in the (0,1),(1,0), (1,1), and (1,-1) directions?

Comment: You are right. What I mean to say is I want to count how many vertical edges there are in an image. (If that makes it more clear)

Comment: Does a vertical edge need to have a precisely horizontal gradient?  Horizontal within +/-5 degrees?  15 degrees?  Do you already have the edges defined or just the pixel-wise gradients?  Do you care more about total length of vertical edges or total number of vertical edges (total length would be pretty easy but total number would likely require you to run some sort of clustering algorithm)?

Comment: +/- 10-15 degrees seems like a good amount to account for. What I have is the edges as pixels in an image. I would like the total number of vertical edges, because that would be a nicer way to compare the numbers for cities and landscapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the total number of pixels comprising horizontal vs vertical edges, I would suggest defining some threshold for horizontal vs vertical (say 15 degrees).  So you can count the number of elements of `theta` for which 
`abs(theta) < pi/12` (horizontal)
or `abs(theta) > pi-pi/12` (horizontal)
or `pi/2 - pi/12 < abs(theta) < pi/2+pi/12` (vertical)

What you're storing in `v` and `h` are the vertical and horizontal components of the gradient at each point and what you need is to compare the values of `v` and `h` to determine for each point if the gradient vector should count as horizontal or vertical.  Comparing `theta` is probably the most intuitive way to do this.

In order to get the number of elements of theta that satisfy a particular condition, I would suggest using a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
sum(1 for i in theta if (abs(i)<pi/12) or (abs(i)>pi-pi/12))
```

would give you the number of horizontal edge pixels for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I apply this threshold? Would I use an if condition to apply the conditions you defined above?

Comment: There's lots of ways to do it.  You could loop over theta and use an if statement.  You could forgo the if statement and just add the result of the boolean expression to the counter (1 for true, 0 for false).  You could also use a generator expression which I think is the fastest way to do it.  I edited the answer to include an example of that approach.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you're counting theta in order to get horizontal/vertical edges? Also, in the generator expression you wrote, what you're doing is getting 1 if the i satisfies the condition and going through all the values in theta and summing those 1s?

Comment: I'm counting pixels belonging to horizontal or vertical edges so in the end you would get the total length (or a good approximation of it) of the horizontal or vertical edges.  If you want to count the number of edges regardless of length then you'll have to group the pixels into edges somehow.  Once you did that, you could count them in the same way as above, you would just use a theta that's per edge vs per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hough transform fits more to your needs if you want to count or control how many linear features you have in your image, either you could count how many linear feature for each specific orientation (in the hough space). As soon you are using Python, [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) and [this](https://alyssaq.github.io/2014/understanding-hough-transform/) link might be helpful!